# Add a java application to the gnome menu

Tags: gnome, java, appmenu

I have a .jar application and I wanna add it to the gnome menu to run it from there, it must run with root privileges.

I did a file called java_application.desktop in /usr/share/applications. The content of the file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Java app
GenericName=My java app
Exec=Exec=gnome-terminal -x 'sudo java -jar .tlauncher/TLauncher-2.8.jar'
Icon=/usr/share/icons/Papirus/64x64/apps/java.svg
Type=Application
Terminal=true
StartupNotify=true
Categories=Games
```

If I execute the command: `sudo java -jar .java_projects/java_app.jar` in the terminal it works.

I've followed the suggestion of @jpbrain. Now the terminal opens, asks for the sudo password and the app opens... but closes after some seconds.

Gnome 40, Fedora 34 (I know it's a Ubuntu forum but I think you can help with this as the problem is about Gnome)

Comment: Hi @Gaspar. I understand sudo will not work within the .desktop file. Elevation of credentials has to be handled by the app.

Comment: try replacing: 

Exec=gnome-terminal -x 'sudo java -jar .java_projects/java_app.jar'

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: I did checkit. It is a problem with the app itself. It chrashes with sudo. Even if you put that absolute path it loads and then exits. When you do it without sudo it works.

Comment: Thanks, now it works

Answer (score 0):

Install the software Menu editor.
Open the software and click the '+' on the left top corner to add a launcher.
Paste the command

```
sudo java -jar .tlauncher/TLauncher-2.8.jar
```

in the empty box against the 'command.'
Slide the radio button of 'Run in terminal' to on.
On the menu bar, there is a right-pointed triangle icon and that can be clicked to test the launcher.
You may change the icon and the description of the software

Comment: It just keeps saying that the program cannot be found...

Comment: Hmm, that means the path to the executable file is wrong. I have changed the path in the answer.